# ngModel in select don't get update from custom pipe

Tags: angular

I've created a custom impure pipe to use in my ngFor like below

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedRole" name="selectedRole">
<option *ngFor="let role of roles| myFilter" [ngValue]="role.name">{{role.name}}</option>
</select>
Selected role : {{selectedRole}} //incorrect!
```

The presentation is working as expected, however the variable `selectedRole` is not getting any update when myFilter did the dynamic filter, Any idea why? thanks

**Update** : Please see this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/iy8lxFR3pTW4v2cbAU8V
Then try to select the same value for both `select`, you will noticed that the selected data won't update correctly

Comment: What is your expectation? I have trouble understanding what you are trying to achieve :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using same variable name

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedRole" name="role">
<option *ngFor="let role of roles| myFilter" [ngValue]="role.name">{{role.name}}</option>
</select>
Selected role : {{selectedRole}} //works
```

**Reason : `role` is the object which is used in the ngFor for iteration.**

Comment: my bad, the same variable is just me want to simplify the example. My actual code is already different. and it still not work. I'll update the example

Comment: Can you create a plunker to reproduce. What is the type of `selectedRole` in your typescript code

Comment: plunker added, hope it's help describe what i'm facing

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedRole" name="role">
<option *ngFor="let role of roles| myFilter" [value]="role">{{role.name}}</option>
</select>
Selected role : {{selectedRole}}
```